# Trying to connect HC-06 with Flutter Blue Plus

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

#### Hello. I'm trying to connect my HC-06 device from my phone with bluetooth.

When I try to connect, it just prints "Connecting..." but nothing else and HC-06's light is keep blinking. At first, tapping on HC-06's tile returns me it's UUID but after once, it never showed again. I'm just getting this on debug console:

```
I/flutter (15506): Connecting...
D/BluetoothGatt(15506): refresh() - device: 00:02:5B:00:A5:A6
D/clearGattCache(15506): CLEAR GATT CACHE: true
```

I tried different libraries but none of them solve my problem.

My code here:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';


class Bluetooth5 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Bluetooth5({super.key});

  @override
  State<Bluetooth5> createState() => Bluetooth5State();
}

class Bluetooth5State extends State<Bluetooth5> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
              future: FlutterBluePlus.instance.bondedDevices,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else {
                  List<BluetoothDevice>? data = snapshot.data;
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: data!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            BluetoothDevice device = data[index];
                            Stream<BluetoothDeviceState> stateStream =
                                device.state;
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(device.name),
                              subtitle: Text(device.id.toString()),
                              onTap: () {
                                print("Connecting...");
                                device.connect(autoConnect: false).then((_) {
                                  print("Connection successful.");
                                }).catchError((error) {
                                  print("Connection error: $error");
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),

                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              }),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, i gave permission on manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```